# Codecademy Student Becomes the Teacher

Tags: python

i have a problem with a lesson in Codecademy. Someone can help me ?

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


def average(numbers):
    total = 0
    total = sum(numbers)
    result = float(total) / len(numbers)
    return result

def get_average(student):
    homework = 0.1 * average(student["homework"])
    quizzes = 0.3 * average(student["quizzes"])
    tests = 0.6 * average(student["tests"])
    return homework + quizzes + tests

student = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for each in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)
```

"Oops, try again. Does your get_class_average function take exactly one input (a list of students)? Your code threw a "list indices must be integers, not str" error."

Comment: Get rid of your `student` list. Change `each` to `student`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`student` is a global list. It's unclear why you're trying to pass it to `get_average()` inside your for loop (or why it exists at all). You probably meant `get_average(each)`.